# Python 2.7 and QGIS 2.6: Subtracting two values and append ID of feature to list

Tags: python, python-2.7, qgis

I would like to subtract two values retrieved from qgs feature iterator objects and append the value of the feature id to a list depending on a condition.

In the context of qgis, I have two layers:
roadsLayer
pathsLayer

What I have so far returns an empty list:

```
evenList = []
azimuthRoadsIDX = roadsLayer.fieldNameIndex('azimuth')
azimuthPathsIDX = pathsLayer.fieldNameIndex('azimuth')
roads = roadsLayer.getFeatures()
paths = pathsLayer.getFeatures()
for feat in roads:
    for feature in paths:
        roadsAzimuth = feat.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX]
        pathsAzimuth = feature.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX]
        if (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimiuth == 90) or (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimth == -270):
            evenList.append(feature.id())
```

Don't know why, but this works. The only problem is it doesn't work in all cases (even when roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimuth == 90, it is not appended in some cases):

```
for feat in roadsLayer.getFeatures():
    roadsAzimuth = feat.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX]
    for feature in pathsLayer.getFeatures():
        pathsAzimuth = feature.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX]
        if (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimiuth == 90) or (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimth == -270):
            evenList.append(feature.id())
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the `feat.attributes()` dictionary contains `QVariant` objects which must be converted to Python objects using `attribute.toPyObject()`. Also, you're defining `roadsAzimuth` twice, is that a typo?

Comment: @F.X. yes, typo, sorry.  I think i found my sol'n...but i don't know why the first version doesn't work and the second does.

Comment: both pieces of code are identical, I  assume your problem reside in the other parts of your code.