# Python 2.7 for QGIS 2.6 : append to list if in range

Tags: python, python-2.7, range

I'm trying to test whether or not the value falls within a range. If yes, I'm looking to append it to a list. This seems simple enough, but I'm making a mistake somewhere I'm not seeing.

In the context of QGIS, which I'm using this code for, I have two layers:
roadsLayer
pathsLayer

```
firstList = []
secondList = []
azimuthRoadsIDX = roadsLayer.fieldNameIndex('azimuth')
azimuthPathsIDX = pathsLayer.fieldNameIndex('azimuth')
for feat in roadsLayer.getFeatures():
    roadsAzimuth = feat.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX]
    for feature in pathsLayer.getFeatures():
        pathsAzimuth = feature.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX]
        difference = roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimuth
        if (-100 < difference < -80):
            firstList.append(feature.id())
        if (260 < difference < 280):
            firstList.append(feature.id())
        if (80 < difference < 100):
            secondList.append(feature.id())
        if (-280 < difference < -260):
            secondList.append(feature.id())
```

The list appends all values, which is incorrect.

Comment: What is returned by feature.id()?

Comment: I think more code (slightly more) is necessary to diagnose your issue.

Comment: when you say "the list appends all values," which list are you referring to?  give us an example value for `difference` and the contents of `firstList` and `secondList` after running this code.

Comment: @Shashank I just added more code

Comment: @dbliss the lists i'm referring to are both oddList and evenList. I just added more code to explain what difference is (difference in azimuth values for two different lines)

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich feature.id() is the id value of the QGIS feature

Comment: @dbliss Excuse me, I meant to say that i'm appending to firstList and secondList. I got my param names mixed up, because I changed it to generalize for this thread.

Comment: what makes you say that it is incorrect for the two lists to append all values of `feature.id()`?  (see my answer.)

Comment: Your problem is not Python. Your problem is your logic and data you are using. You have two loops. Second loop works independently of outer loop, so there may be a chance that you have 2 lists with the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `feature` is being passed through the code with every one of the values for `roadsAzimuth`.  Hence, each `feature` is associated (potentially) with multiple values for `difference`.  These values for difference could be anything (as far as we know) -- some could be small, some could be large, some positive, some negative.  Hence, there's no reason `firstList` and `secondList` shouldn't both receive all the ids.

Instead of using `firstList` and `secondList` and appending to them, what you want to do is something like this:

```
results_dict = {}
azimuthRoadsIDX = roadsLayer.fieldNameIndex('azimuth')
azimuthPathsIDX = pathsLayer.fieldNameIndex('azimuth')
for i, feat in enumerate(roadsLayer.getFeatures()):
    roadsAzimuth = feat.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX]
    results_dict[i] = ([], [])
    for feature in pathsLayer.getFeatures():
        pathsAzimuth = feature.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX]
        difference = roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimuth
        if (-100 < difference < -80):
            results_dict[i][0].append(feature.id())
        if (260 < difference < 280):
            results_dict[i][0].append(feature.id())
        if (80 < difference < 100):
            results_dict[i][1].append(feature.id())
        if (-280 < difference < -260):
            results_dict[i][1].append(feature.id())
```

Now you have a `firstList` and a `secondList` for each `feat`.  Each key in the dictionary corresponds to an index in `roadsLayer.getFeatures()`.  Each value is a tuple with two lists -- `firstList` and `secondList` -- that contain the ids whose difference is associated with that list for that `feat`.

Comment: all of the paths are perpendicular lines to the roads and are only associated with one road each. Originally, i had a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569546/python-2-7-and-qgis-2-6-subtracting-two-values-and-append-id-of-feature-to-list?noredirect=1#comment47289696_29569546) because I know that most of the difference values are exactly 270, -270, 90, or -90. I started testing with a range because some of the paths fall on road vertices and are thus not exactly perpendicular. I'm trying to restructure my question to reflect the direct association of paths and roads

Comment: if we assume `difference` is always in `(270, -270, 90, -90)`, my point still stands.  i'd be interested to see what you get when you run the code in my answer.

Comment: I get a dictionary with keys being the index of roads, as you mentioned. I may be able to use this is I diminish the range a bit. My issue currently with this method is that the same path is associated with roads that it isn't connected to (simply because the difference in azimuth lies within the range defined). I may need to do a geometry intersection condition as well.

Comment: "the same path is associated with roads that it isn't connected to" -- that's a problem with the logic of your `for` loops.  you're calculating `difference` for every road/path combination (regardless of connectivity).

Comment: yeah, i'm realizing that. before it wasn't an issue, because with a precision of 2, only the perpendicular lines made it on the list. i'm going to accept your answer, because it answers the original question.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
addlist = firstList if (-100 < difference < -80 or 260 < difference < 280) else secondList
addlist.append(feature.id())
```

Comment: this does not address why the user's code is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple code for you

maybe you need to check value of feature.id()

#!/usr/bin/python

aList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc'];

aList.append( 2009 );

print "Updated List : ", aList;

Comment: this does not address why the user's code is failing.